# detect h264 access unit possible location

Tags: video, h.264, http-live-streaming, mpeg2-ts

as you know access unit delimiter in h264 is optional

but sometimes we want to know its possible location as if we want to create mpeg-ts container

i'am using https://mradionov.github.io/h264-bitstream-viewer/ to parse video.h264

it have 5924 nalu as this sequence [7,8,6 then any nalu may be 5 or 1 ] iam not receiving any [7,8,6,9] later only receving 7,8,6 in the first only

this is my [video.h264](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1zVIaauQBkL8SGY5bVSE-J71mUug9SrHo/view?usp=sharing) file iam using
see my parser screen shots

[image]

this is the last nalu header details i want to detect the boundary on each new frame
[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is actually fairly complicated.

Looking at this stream I see two IDRs NALus in a row. If one VCL NAL in an AU is an IDR, they all must be, so the first AU is *probably* the SPS/PPS/SEI/IDR/IDR.

Then then next AUs are *probably* two slices each.

to know for sure, you must parse the sps to be the number of macro blocks from `pic_width_in_mbs_minus1 + pic_height_in_map_units_minus1 + 2`

Then you must parse the `slice_header()` and `slice_data()` and run the algorithm documented in ISO 14496-10 to obtain the list of macro blocks in the slice. Once all the macro blocks are accounted for, you found the end of the slice.

Comment: can i use rtp timestamp to identify aud possible location as i found on the ''rfc6184" say that " only one timestamp per coded frame can be
         conveyed in the RTP timestamp"